# Can you send AWS RDS Postgres logs to a AWS Hadoop cluster easily?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, rds

In particular, I'd like to push all of the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements from my Postgres logs to a AWS Hadoop cluster and have a nice way to search them to see the history of a row or rows.

I'm not a Hadoop expert in any way, so let me know if this is a red herring.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**flume**](http://flume.apache.org) to send logs from your RDS instance to Hadoop cluster. Using *flume* you could use *regex interceptor* to filter events and send just INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements. Hadoop does not make your data searchable so you have to use something like [**Solr**](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

You could either get the data to Hadoop first and then run bunch of MapReduce jobs to insert data into Solr. Or you could directly configure flume to write data to Solr, see link below.

Links:

1. [Using flume solr sink](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLUME/How+to+Setup+Solr+Sink+for+Flume)
2. [Flume Regex Filtering Interceptor](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#regex-filtering-interceptor)

EDIT:

It seems like RDS instances don't have SSH access, which means that you cannot natively run flume on the RDS instance itself but you have to periodically [get the logs of the RDS instance manually](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html) to a machine (this could be a EC2 instance) which has flume configured.